# Components duplicate, triples, quadruple onClick React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that allows users to create channels/chatrooms to talk in

I have created some logic so that when the user presses a button they create a channel, function: `onCreateChannel`.

This function changes the `createChannel` state to `true` which then shows the  code stored in `showChannelInput`. This is the behaviour I want so that the user can type the name of their channel and assign it a category.

When the user then fills in the input and selects a category the FIRST time it's fine and the behaviour I want works, however, when the user clicks the `Create Channel` button on the 2nd 3rd and 4th try the `showChannelInput` code duplicates, triples/ quadruples every time.

I want that every time the user clicks the `Create Channel` button that it only shows the `showChannelInput` code once each time.... Can anyone see why this is happening? Am I making sense?

Code below:

```
export default function Channels() {
  const { currentUser, venue, venueUpdateHandler } = useContext(AuthContext);

[...]
  const channelData = setupChannels(venue !== null ? venue.chatRooms : []); //venue is coming from auth context and has the chatrooms in it as an object key

  const [channelName, setChannelName] = useState('');

  const [channels, setChannels] = useState(channelData);

  const [createChannel, setCreateChannel] = useState(false);

  const onFormControlChange = (event, key) => {
    if (event.target.value.length <= 100) {
      if (channels[key]) {
        let existingChannels = [...channels];
        existingChannels[key].name = event.target.value;
        setChannels(existingChannels);
      } else {
        setChannelName(event.target.value); // add new channel
      }
    }
  };

[...]

  const onAddChannelKeyPress = event => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      onAddChannelClick();
    }
  };

  const onCreateChannel = () => {
    setCreateChannel(true);
  };

  const onAddChannelClick  = () => {
    if (channelName === '') {
      return;
    }

    let existingChannels = [...channels];
    let newChannel = {
      key: existingChannels.length,
      name: channelName,
      deletable: true,
      markedForDelete: false,
      category: null
    };
    existingChannels.push(newChannel);
    setChannels(existingChannels);
    setChannelName('');
    setCreateChannel(false);
 };


  [...]




  let displayExistingChannels =  null;
  if (channels !== null){
   displayExistingChannels = (
      channels.map(channel => {
        return (
          <Grid key={channel.key} item style={styles.gridItem} justify="space-between">
            <ChannelListItem
              channel={channel}
              isSaving={isSaving}
              onDeleteChannelClick={onDeleteChannelClick}
              key={channel.key}
              onFormControlChange={onFormControlChange}
              onUndoChannelClick={onUndoChannelClick}
            />
          </Grid>
        )
      })
    )
  }


  let showChannelInput = null;
  if (createChannel) {
    showChannelInput = (
      channels.map(channel => {
        return (
          <Grid key={channel.key} item style={styles.gridItem} justify="space-between">
            <Grid item style={styles.gridItem}>
              <ChannelFormControl
                channelName={channelName}
                isSaving={isSaving}
                onFormControlChange={onFormControlChange}
                onAddChannelClick={onAddChannelClick} 
                onAddChannelKeyPress={onAddChannelKeyPress}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
              <ChannelCategory
                visible={true}
                onChange={value => onAddCategory(value, channel.key)}
                title="Add your channel to a category so that users can find it with ease"
                selected={channel.category}
                name={channel.key} // unique for every channel
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        )
      })
    )
  }

  return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete='off' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Card style={styles.card}>
        <ActionResult result={actionResult} onClose={onActionResultClose} />
        <CardContent>
          <Box padding={3}>
            <FormLegend title={`${formTitle} (${channels.length})`} description={formDescription} />

            <Box marginTop={3} width='50%'>
              <Grid container direction='column' justify='flex-start' alignItems='stretch' spacing={1}>
                <ActionButton
                  labelNormal='Create Channel'
                  labelAction='Creating Channel'
                  onClickHandler={onCreateChannel}
                />
                  {displayExistingChannels}
                  {showChannelInput}
                <Grid item>
                  <ActionButton
                    isSaving={isSaving}
                    labelNormal='Save'
                    labelAction='Saving'
                    onClickHandler={onClickSave} 
                  />
                  <Button variant='text' color='secondary' style={styles.resetButton} onClick={onResetClick}>
                    Reset
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      [...]
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are using `channels.map` and on every time your `onAddChannelClick` is triggered, it pushes a new channel to `channels`. So, instead of `channels.map` in `showChannelInput`, you should create a new variable, which will get the newest channel from `channels` like this:

```js
const newChannel = channels[channels.length - 1];
```

and use it. Or without new variable you can write in every attribute for example this `selected={channels[channels.length - 1].category}` instead of this `selected={channel.category}`

Answer (score 1):

code change to fix issue

```
  let showNewChannelInput = null;
  const newChannel = channels[channels.length - 1]; 
  if (createChannel) {
    showNewChannelInput = (
          <Grid key={newChannel.key} item style={styles.gridItem} justify="space-between">
            <Grid item style={styles.gridItem}>
              <ChannelFormControl
                channelName={channelName}
                isSaving={isSaving}
                onFormControlChange={onFormControlChange}
                onAddChannelClick={onAddChannelClick} // adding a new channel input box does this need an attributes prop which is an object
                onAddChannelKeyPress={onAddChannelKeyPress}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
              <ChannelCategory
                visible={true}
                onChange={value => onAddCategory(value, newChannel.key)}
                title="Add your channel to a category so that users can find it with ease"
                selected={newChannel.category}
                name={newChannel.key} // unique for every channel
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
    )
  }
```